# Country Name Pattern

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I am Confused how to make a country name pattern like star pattern in php

For Example I want to make A pattern Like This in php Using Arrays And For Loops Can any one help me I didn't find on Internet.

P

PA

PAK

PAKI

PAKIS

PAKIST

PAKISTA

PAKISTAN

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Please [post your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can see.

Comment: You need to explain your question more thoroughly; what is a 'star pattern' in context? What does the addition of letters have to do with that 'pattern'? (Also, I suspect that when you explain what you're trying to do, it'll become obvious that something similar is available on the net).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$country="AUSTRALIA";
$len=strlen($country);
for($i=1;$i<=$len;$i++)
{
  echo substr($country,0,$i),"\n";
}
?>
```

**Output**

```
A
AU
AUS
AUST
AUSTR
AUSTRA
AUSTRAL
AUSTRALI
AUSTRALIA
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/282668)**

Comment: Thank you I got it now Problem Solved :)